# R Plot two graphs; One large, one small

Tags: r

[I want to make a figure similar to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4F6z.jpg)

See how the bottom portion is tiny... how do I do that?

I'm ok in ggplots2 so give me your expertise please.

I do not need to plot 2 values on the larger one. Essentially, I know how to generate everything I want from this figure, except how to make a tiny plot under a larger one (sans photoshop)

I have data.frames that contain the transcript information in the figure at the bottom, I'm only interested in one gene. To plot the genes you would do something like this

```
plot(transcript, type="l", lwd=2)
points(exons, type="l", lwd=3, col="blue")
points(utrExons, type="l", lwd=3)
```

To plot the large figure it would look like this

```
plot(genetic.variant, pch=16)
```

An exhaustive internet search turned into bupkis, how do you make two figures in the same plotting area with one of them being much smaller than the other?

Comment: If you add the code you've already got to your Q then you might get a bit more interest from potential answerers. Questions with [reproducible examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) generally get people's attention here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use layout

```
layout(c(1,2),widths=c(5,1),heights=c(5,1),T)
par(mar=c(1,1,1,1)
```

and just change the heights depending on your preference

Answer (score 1):

With base graphics you can do something like this

```
dd<-data.frame(x=1:100, y1=runif(100), y2=cumsum(rnorm(100)))
layout(matrix(1:2, ncol=1), heights=c(3,1))
par(mar=c(0,3,3,2))
plot(y1~x,dd, xaxt="n", xlab="")
par(mar=c(3,3,0,2))
plot(y2~x,dd)
```

[image]